# What mongodb query will limit the results of a nested list

Tags: mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{
    "username":"test",
    "comments":
    [
        {
            "commentId":"53453445",
            "message":"Hello this is a message"
        },
        {
            "commentId":"53453445",
            "message":"Hello this is a message"
        },
        {
            "commentId":"53453445",
            "message":"Hello this is a message"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I limit the comments to only display 2 items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$slice` operator:

`db.collection.find( { "username":"test" }, { comments: {$slice: 2 } } );`